# undefined class 'UserCredential' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to implement Google login screen using Flutter.

```
 UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email:email, password: password);
```

The editor, for the line above, says:

```
  Undefined class 'UserCredential'
```

How can I fix it? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: import package `firebase_auth.dart`

Comment: its already imported

Comment: Run `pub get`/`pub upgrade` to make sure you have the right version of firebase_auth.dart

Comment: then most likely you are using outdated version of `firebase_auth`, where `UserCredential` was `AuthResult` use AuthResult or update your firebase packages version.

Answer (score 0):

updated my firebase packages version using

```
npm update -g firebase-tools
```

And then restarted my IDE.